# Localstack Pro Unable to pull docker image when running ECS task

Tags: amazon-ecs, localstack

I've created the following resources using localstack-pro:

- ECS cluster
- ECR repository
- I've pushed a docker image to the ECR repository and created a task definition that uses that image.

I'm trying to run the ECS task using the following command:

```
awslocal ecs run-task \
  --task-definition "arn:aws:ecs:us-east-1:000000000000:task-definition/test-task-definition:2" \
  --cluster "arn:aws:ecs:us-east-1:000000000000:cluster/test-cluster"
```

but get the following error:

```
docker.errors.NotFound: 404 Client Error for http+docker://localhost/v1.42/images/create?tag=latest&fromImage=localhost.localstack.cloud%3A4510%2Ftest-image-repo%2Ftest-image-repo: Not Found ("manifest for localhost.localstack.cloud:4510/test-image-repo/test-image-repo:latest not found: manifest unknown: manifest unknown")
```

Any idea on how to resolve this issue?

Comment: It would be good to reach out to LocalStack support, since Pro support is provided for services like ECS & ECR